# Google Apps script:Trying to open each doc in a folder, extract its TOC and write it to another doc

Tags: google-apps-script

First, thanks to Serge insas for enough help to even write this script!

The script runs, but doesn't give me anything like the desired result. 
What I want to do is
(1) Create a new document in a given folder(Let's call it 'myfolder') and write a title for it.
     That works--sort of. I get a document, but it's icon is a tiny image for a doc file but with its corner turned over. It only opens in the viewer. It does have the title, but nothing that I tried to write to it subsequently.

(2) Get an array of all the files in 'myfolder'. That's where the Serge's help came in. They need to be converted into readable documents. I THINK that worked (More on this later). At least the debugger did not throw an error. I ended up with a 'contents' array.

(3) For each of those documents, get the file name and extract the Table of Contents. Append each of those to the doc created in (1). To do this, I used a for loop which iterated from one to contents.length. Now the FIRST problem arose. Whatever contents.length brought back wasn't right because the next loop, where the processing occurred errored out at approximately the number of documents, not counting these little half-docs the script generated. I got around this by a try-catch construction that stopped when it hit an undefined file. That and the execution transcript suggested that the script did go through that loop.

So here's the BIG problem. Whatever those little half-docs were, nothing other than the first introductory line was written to them.

The debugger is useless.
(a) It doesn't show me the log file. Just a date.
(b) If I place a breakpoint, it MAY stop at it, but I see mostly a list of objects. If I click on the + sign, I get a list of methods. A few of the non-object variables are shown. It's impossible to step through the code because it can take up to three minutes to go from one line to the next, so it's been rather tough to debug this.

The only info I could garner was that the execution transcript did suggest that I did get doc objects from the files.

I think the problem is with a**doc = DocumentApp.openById(docObject[jj]);** which is in bold in the code below.

Sorry for the strange error handling; I was trying to get some insight into what was wrong.  Alas, the debugger tells me that Err is an string and gives me no value.

Whether the rest of the code works or not, I can't tell if it does, indeed error out the first time it hits the bolded line.

Thanks for your patience.

```
function listDocTOCsInFolder()
{
  // Thanks to crucial help from Serge insas via Stack Overflow.
  var afolder;       // Folder you want to work on
  var contents;      // Files in the folder
  var TOCListDoc;    // Document you will create to hold your TOC List
  var docObject = []; // Holds a list of documents created from contents
  var aname;
  var adoc;
  var err = "";
  var isErr = false;

  TOCListDoc = DocsList.createFile("TOCList", "Document TOC List");

  afolder = DocsList.getFolderById("0B-UcimyrHLl2bm1OanExaHotc2M")
  //Can't figure out what exactly constitutes the path of a folder.  

  TOCListDoc.addToFolder(afolder);

 // Get all the document files in your named folder. Unfortunately,they are not document objects
  var contents = afolder.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT);

  // This loop gives you an array of DocumentApp objects.
  for (var ii = 0; ii < contents.length; ii++) 
  {   
    docObject.push(DocumentApp.openById(contents[ii].getId()));
  }  
     // Now you can do a for loop to gather up the contents into one document.
    Logger.log(contents.length);

    // It isn't clear what this actually gets, because unless I set a trap of
    // undefined documents, the loop keeps right on going.
    var len = docObject.length;
    var jj = 0;
    for(jj = 0; jj < len; II++ )
    {
      try 
      {

        **adoc = DocumentApp.openById(docObject[jj]);**
      }
      catch(err)
      {
        isErr = true;
      }

      if(!isErr)
      {
      // Get the information you want to write to your list doc

      var TOC = adoc.getAs(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS);
      logger.log(TOC);
      aname = adoc.getName();

      Logger.log(aname);

      body.appendParagraph(counter, name);

      body.appendParagraph(TOC);
      //.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
      }
      else
      {
        Logger.log("Errored out");
      }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say

> "For each of those documents, get the file name and extract the Table
>   of Contents. Append each of those to the doc created in (1)

that's indeed what you should do... you used this code :

```
  // Get the information you want to write to your list doc

  var TOC = adoc.getAs(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS);
  logger.log(TOC);
```

but doing this you assume that the first element in this document is necessarily the TOC and I'm not sure you can do that !!

What I I would try is to iterate through all the document's elements and check the type of each element, **then copy the one that is a TOC** to your new document.

See eventually [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939031/how-to-delete-blank-pages-in-a-multipage-document) to check how you could iterate into the document's elements and check their types, the purpose of this script was different but I guess the approach should help you.

Good luck

Comment: The reason for the convoluted need for changing the document type of each document acquired by DocumentApp to the type generated by DocsList was the desire to use the method, searchResult = docbody.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS), so that I would not have to do that kind of iteration. Unfortunately, what I have found is that a SearchResult doesn't seem to translate into anything I can use. I'll close this question and ask this as a new question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
`for(jj = 0; jj < len; II++ )` 
try
 `for(jj = 0; jj < len; jj++ )`
 instead
and: read again the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)...

Comment: Thanks for spotting this because I might have looked at this for hours without catching it. Originally, it was all II, which I then changed to jj, but obviously, I missed the increment. However, I had run it all with II and ii, and have now run it again with the same delimiter. The same problem exists. I am sure now that the FIRST prolem is with the line:
**adoc = DocumentApp.openById(docObject[jj]);**
I guess this one has to be solved before we can look and problem 2.