# Removing Blank Paragraph after appendTable()

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm merging two Google Docs together, by appending each of the elements from one document to the other. This works great, except for when I use appendTable() I'm getting an extra blank line after each table. After some digging, I discovered that this is actually [a blank paragraph element](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3990).

In trying to remove this blank paragraph I thought maybe I could, after appending the table, remove the next sibling, like so:

```
var table = body.appendTable(element);
body.removeChild(table.getNextSibling());
```

However, I'm greeted with a, `Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.` message when I try this method.

Has anyone else figured out a way to remove this blank paragraph after using appendTable()?

Comment: You have to do it in a second step ( when it's not the last element anymore) by removing all empty paragraphs. Btw, have you seen this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939031/how-to-delete-blank-pages-in-a-multipage-document

Answer (score 0):

Developers documentations says that a Google Doc can't end with a paragraph, so one will always be automatically inserted.