# Combining Google Documents in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, document

I'm trying to write a script to concatenate multiple documents into a single, large document. Essentially, the inputs are all the documents in a specified folder and the output is a single, combined document.

I'm unsure as to how to go about this. Since [getContentAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#getContentAsString) returns plain text, should I be looking into returning it as a [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob) and using that? Are there any scripts that provide this functionality already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Henrique's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog%20://)
It will need some minor modifications to do what you want..