# Appending the body of one doc to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I just want to add the body of one document on to the body of a different document

```
  var tempBody   = DocumentApp.openById(inputDoc).getBody();
  var outputBody = DocumentApp.openById(outputDoc).getBody();
  outputBody = outputBody + tempBody; //this is wrong of course
```

How do you append the body of one doc to the body of another doc. I found all the append commands, but they are all about single element appending not more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at t[his thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog)  .  In case you use other element types you should add more conditions accordingly.