# Embedding a doc into a doc in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-api, embedding

I was trying to see if there was a way I could embed a few documents into a master document using scripts or any other method.  I am writing a thesis consisting of 5 chapters and I want to work on each individually without constantly copy/pasting into the master document.  Plus, this will make things a lot easier on my review committee as they can see at a glance what I changed most recently.
I'm sure this must be possible, but for the life of me, I cannot figure it out.  I'm not great at using Java or apps script, but I can understand the basics if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

-Jacob

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed a document into a document, but you can append the elements of one document to the body of another document. Have a look at the answer to [How can I generate a multipage text document from a single page template in google-apps-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog) for a start.

You should be aware of all the [element types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type), as each has its own handlers - Henrique's answer deals with the three elements that the current documentation says can be contained in a body, but you may find the list isn't exhaustive.