# Google Apps Script add code to copy of a document

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a document bound script in Google Docs that allows me to select a part of some text in a document. Then when I click my menu button it will make a copied document with only the selected text in it. The script then shares the copied document and emails the person that it was shared with them.

I would like it to be possible that the user of the shared document is able to read that document, and send a message back via a form on what he thought about it. So he would also go to a customized menu button, click on it, a form would pop up and he would email me back with the text.

I know how to do this in Google Apps Script manually. I can go to the copied document and just add that script. But how do I automize this? I looked at the Google Apps Script references but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to embed a script in a document using a script.

You could use a template that has a script , make a copy of it and add your content to that copy instead of creating the new doc from scratch.

Depending on the document content it might be very simple ...or just a bit more complex since you will have to add each element in turn.  There are a few examples of this process here:  [How to copy a template and insert content from another document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349641/how-to-copy-a-template-and-insert-content-from-another-document/19349922#comment34124841_19349922) :

Comment: Thanks :) For this to work embedding a script 'somehow' has to be automized. The link that you stated was one of the links that I used in order to create a functionality that copies the script.