# How can I copy file while maintaining formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script

Just to clarify this is a Google Active Script.

Read Google Doc File ( this is a template with place holders and formatting ( bod, tabs, underline etc ) Place holders are `{placeholderName}` I use `Body.replaceText('{placeholderName}', placeholderName)` this works fine.  The data that is inserted is contained within a Google Spreadsheet (that works fine too) I am only trying to maintain formatting in the template file that is modified and then appended to the final file.

```js
 var SerialLetterID = DriveApp.getFileById('google_doc_id').makeCopy('filename').getId();
```

var fBody = DocumentApp.openById(SerialLetterID);

```js
 // an independent copy of the template ( with formatting )
var Template = fBody.getBody().copy();
```

After the data replaces the placeholders

```js
// insert a pageBreak
fBody.getBody().appendPageBreak();

/* 
 this is where I'm getting the issues.. everything works but the getText()
 removes all formatting.  I looked for a getCopy() or something of the like
 but nothing like that seems to exist.  So, in OOP google style how would I     
 copy the page, maintain formatting in the same manner as getText() works?
*/
// add template with placeholders 
fBody.getBody().appendParagraph(Template.getText());
```

I hope that I explained what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How is your question different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987101/how-to-copy-the-content-of-a-google-docs-text-file-to-another-google-text-docume)?

Comment: Thank you.. I hunted and found several but none that were this direct.  I only have one question, I added the couple lines of code, but apparently the document has to be bound to the script.  All the examples I have read and tutorials come from the perspective of using the UI Tools > Script editor. This is being done entirely in a stand alone script.  How, what function binds my 'virtual' file to the script?

Comment: Figured it out... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: A good outcome, then. I wasn't sure you were describing the same problem.