# Make copy of file preserving links inside images in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of a Google Doc that has linked documents in the images. I want to preserve all the attributes in the document.

My code:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(id).makeCopy('Copy of '+ sourceDoc.getName());
```

Already tried something like the solution in this thread: [How to copy content and formatting between Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987101/how-to-copy-content-and-formatting-between-google-docs) , but it doesn't preserve all the attributes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm trying to make a Google App Script that will make a copy of a Google Doc. When trying to do this with the above code, its not preserving all of its attributes like the the linked docs inside the images.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your issue and your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Make a deep copy of a Google Doc using Google Apps Script...

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand about your current situation and goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document where not all of the contents is being copied with your request?

Comment: Try [tag:google-docs-api] instead