# Google Add-on Script with Document Tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I've been coding with PHP, HTML and CSS for a while now.  Just started looking into Google Apps Scripts for creating a custom Add-On.  I've been searching for a while but have been unable to find an answer.

Is it possible to get the text from a user-created table (one that was inserted using the Google Document drop down menu)?

Answer (score 0):

Documents are build with specific elements, it is quite easy to find a table and, from there, retrieve its content.

See in [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog) (Henrique's answer) a script that iterates a doc to see how to do it.

This answer is quite "general" but your question was too... be more specific if you need more specific informations.