# How to merge multiple google docs from data in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to make a script to merge multiple Google Docs (selected from data in a spreadsheet) and create a single merged document.

I know how to do this in Word/Excel and could write it PHP/MySQL but I really would like to try to keep this inside of Google Docs as we are trying to move our documents into the cloud.

I understand about how a the documents are named and how to open it using App Scripts but don't know if this is possible.

Here is an example of my sheet:

Name________ DocPt1_________DocPt2_________DocPt3
Steve_______ GoogleDocA1____GoogleDocB1____GoogleDocC1
Mike________ GoogleDocA1____GoogleDocB2____GoogleDocC1
Drew________ GoogleDocA2____GoogleDocB2____GoogleDocC2
Aaron_______ GoogleDocA2____GoogleDocB1____GoogleDocC1

---

The Script would then lookup each of the documents and copy the contents of each in order into a new document.

Is this even possible? This is my first venture into Google Apps Scripts.

Thanks for any guidance.

Robb

Comment: how about [importrange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)?

Comment: I think he wants to merge text documents from a list. Not spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This souldn't be too hard, have a look at the [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog) to see how to merge any number of documents into one.