# How to copy google doc entire page content with formatting's(images,charts,etc)from a google doc file to another docs in Google docs Script Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste, google-docs, google-docs-api

As per below screenshot, I have a Doc called "Raw". All I need to copy/append this doc pages to other of the Documents like "Document 1, 2, 3...." at the end of its pages using Google script editor ?

[image]

This is my code, am able to achieve this only for text contents, but not as whole page with charts, shapes, formatting, images, etc.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var SOURCE_FILE = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" //Browser Document ID;
  var DESTINATION_FILE = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  
  var SOURCE_FILE_COPY = DocumentApp.openById(SOURCE_FILE).getText();
  //var DESTINATION_FILE_COPY = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var DESTINATION_FILE_COPY = DocumentApp.openById(DESTINATION_FILE).getBody();
  var TEXT = DESTINATION_FILE_COPY.editAsText();
  TEXT.appendText(SOURCE_FILE_COPY);      
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a multipage text document from a single page template in google-apps-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog)

Comment: Thanks @RafaGuillermo, as i mentioned in my question, I need entire contents of google docs page without losing its formatting(charts, shapes, formatting, images, etc.). The link which you provided only for text and paragraphs, which i already had achieved that.

Comment: Have you actually tried using it? It *keeps* all those things you say you want to keep.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, This link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog" worked only for Paragraphs and List Items, but the Table elements lost their formatting.